# Does Google index content generated using javascript?

Tags: javascript, indexing

does Google index content generated using javascript I'm using this function to write the text

```
document.write(String.fromCharCode(...))
```

something like that

```
document.write(String.fromCharCode(60,112,62,65,100,100,32,100,101,115,99,114,105,112,116,105,111,110,32,102,111,114,32,121,111,117,114,32,65,114,116,105,99,108,101,32,102,114,111,109,32,104,101,114,101,46,60,47,112,62,10));
```

and if Google don't index javascript will it regard this code as malicious as this function is also used to generate malicious javascript codes of course I'm not using malicious

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did my answer, answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

Yes/No

Google WILL index content if you give it some hints. For example, you'd need to use the `#!` format and your URLs need to resolve WITHOUT the `#!`. Like Twitter:

http://twitter.com#!/oscargodson and http://twitter.com/oscargodson work. Google sees a link to the first link then forwards onto the second.

For random bits of JS though? Most likely not. Google doesn't give out specific details to their algorithm. They have quitely switched to indexing PDFs, Flash, Docs, and more when before they said they didn't. With the rise of JS, i wouldn't be surprised if they officially did tho sometime soon.

Here are Google's docs on it:
http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/

Comment: That is not really indexing javascript. Google will crawl the ajax link with the "#!", but will still expect server-generated content.

Comment: Why I said `For example, you'd need to use the #! format and your URLs need to resolve WITHOUT the #!`

Answer (score 0):

Yes. As of May of 2014, they publicized their move.

http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com.es/2014/05/understanding-web-pages-better.html